# Override operator across namespaces

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, operator-overloading, argument-dependent-lookup

This question is in regards to C++03.

In my namespace, I typedef a class from a different namespace, then attempt to overload an operator for that class. I understand that typedef is just an alias and not a new type, therefore when ADL kicks in my overload is not used. This wasn't intuitive to me at first. I'm wondering if there is a way to "select" my overload, or somehow "guide" ADL to the correct namespace?

Below is a simplified case:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace boost
{
   template<typename T>
   struct some_type{};

   template<typename T, typename U>
   T& operator<<(T& os, some_type<U> const& obj)
   {
      os << "Boost implementation";
      return os;
   }
}

namespace my
{
   typedef boost::some_type<int> typedefed_type;

   template<typename T>
   T& operator<<(T& os, typedefed_type const& obj)
   {
      os << "My implementation";
      return os;
   }
}

namespace other
{
   template<typename T>
   void f(T const& obj)
   {
      // using namespace my; // ***
      std::cout << obj << std::endl;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   my::typedefed_type obj;
   other::f(obj);
   return 0;
}
```

Here, I am calling `other::f()` with an object from `::my`, even though `obj` is really a typedef of a class in `boost`. This outputs: `Boost implementation`. What can I do to get `My implementation` to run? The line marked `// ***` seems to do it, but I would rather not have `other::f()` care about what namespaces the template parameter came from.

Comment: You cannot hijack other people's overloads like that. Use a proper wrapper type around some_type, rather than a typedef.

Comment: @n.m., are you saying "should not" or "cannot"?

Comment: @RSahu I think I'm saying "cannot". Wait, let me check ... *glances at a comment above* ... yep, definitely "cannot".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hijack the generic implementation in `boost` namespace by overloading the function in your own file that uses the same namespace.

Continue to have your own generic implementation in `my` namespace and then add:

```
namespace boost
{
   typedef some_type<int> typedefed_type;

   template<typename T>
   T& operator<<(T& os, typedefed_type const& obj)
   {
      return my::operator<<(os, obj);
   }
}
```

Then, your use of of the `<<` operator can be simple in `other` namespace.

```
namespace other
{
   template<typename T>
   void f(T const& obj)
   {
      std::cout << obj << std::endl;
   }
}
```